# get text from dialog android

Tags: java, android

after executing showDialog method the value of String s stays the same and doesn't change by the input of the editText

can anyone tell me why?

```
String s ="";

public void showDialog(String text) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialouge, null))
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Dialog f = (Dialog) dialog;
                    EditText editText = f.findViewById(R.id.markers_name);
                    s=editText.getText().toString();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Showing a dialog does not pause your code's execution. Any code you have immediately after the call to `showDialog()` is not going to wait until that button is clicked.

Comment: Oh! Didn't know that, but is there a way to get the input from the dialog to use it somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the issue. You didn't really give enough info to be certain. Anyhoo, just don't call any code that uses `s` until that button click, and you should be good. Or, put the code that needs that input into a separate method, and call that method from the click with the input as an argument.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much